# How to avoid android countdown timer starting new activity after the app is closed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, timer, countdown

I have a countdown timer method in main activity in which on finish method starts another activity. My problem is that while running the first activity and if I closed the app before the timer finishes. The app open the next activity by opening application. It works perfect if i waited till the timer finishes. I didn't minimize the app but I closed it, but it starts when the timer stops.

```
public void onFinish()
{
Intent resultPage = new Intent(context,ResultPage.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("score",score);
resultPage.putExtras(b);
startActivity(resultPage);
finish();
}
```

Comment: overide `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` method and stop timer in both method.

Comment: call [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel()) on the [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) at the end of activity lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopTimer();
    super.onDestroy();

}
private void stopTimer() {

        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is isTimerRunning variable? I think timer is the variable for my countdown timer. should i write those methods outside my countdown method?

Comment: isTimerRunning  is a flag value which i use to manage other things just avoid these flag value ,its show timer is running or not  .

Comment: OK i have tried as you guided me but still it tries to open the app but this time with the app crushing.